# negation of a number

Tags: c, bit-manipulation

```
int x=8; 
int k=~(x); 

printf(%d",k)
```

output: 9

The explanation for it is:

```
8= 00000000 00000000 00000000 00001000 
~8 = 11111111 11111111 11111111 11110111
```

we are assigning it in integer hence most significant bit (MSB)is the sign bit 
bcz MSB is 1 hence it is treated as -ve no. 
when u try to print it then before printing compiler will take 2's complement hence it becomes : 
2's complement of `(~8)=9` 
2's complement of `11111111 11111111 11111111 11110111` is `00000000 00000000 00000000 00001000 +1 = 1001 = 9`

So my question is what if we do `k=-9` then if we print k, it will print -9. when does exactly it takes 2's complement

Comment: Um, wait, ~8 is not equal to 9.

Comment: output is -9 ..where is 9 result ??

Comment: output is not 9 it's -9 check properly

Comment: The question just has a couple typos.  I think the OP meant to say `int x=-8` and also missed an opening quote for the `printf` argument.  No worries though.  This happens when people write questions; it's easy to make typos.  But agree with Karthik, it is important to check your question carefully before posting.

Comment: Output of the program you've shown us should indeed be -9. Remember, 2's complement negation would be ~x+1.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The direct but highly technical answer to your question is that the two's complement is taken for an integer value when it is operated on by the negation operator.

More informally: The two's complement of an integer is **exactly** the same thing as its negation.

If you write

```
-9
```

you get the two's complement of `9` which is `-9`.  If you write

```
-(-9)
```

you get the two's complement of `-9` which is `9`.

Since you mentioned the the tilde operator (`~`) in your question, let's look at that.  The tilde operator is the **one's complement**, which is what you get when you "flip every bit".  Notice:

```
~(-3) = 2
~(-2) = 1
~(-1) = 0
~0 = -1
~1 = -2
~2 = -3
```

In general

```
~x = -x - 1
```

They're different.  Use `-` for two's complement and `~` for one's complement.

Many people like to rewrite this as

```
-x = ~x + 1
```

which gives a hint about how to design a circuit for negation.  It means "to find the negation of a number (i.e., its two's complement) you *flip every bit then add 1*".

Answer (score 0):

The standard for negating a 2's compliment number is to flip all the bits, then add one.

Answer (score 0):

```
when u try to print it then before printing compiler will take 2's complement hence it becomes
```

This is not true.It is reverse actually. Negative numbers are stored as 2's compliment not converted before printing.
`-9` is stored as `FFFFFFFFFFFFFFF7` and converted back to -9 when you print it.

Answer (score 0):

~8 is -9 
[check here](http://www.binaryhexconverter.com/decimal-to-binary-converter)
numbers are represented in 2's compliment. Invert the number and add 1 you will get the positive value of the same number.
what you have said is correct for number representation

2's complement of -9 is 
11111111 11111111 11111111 11110111 is

00000000 00000000 00000000 00001000 +1

00000000 00000000 00000000 00001001

which 9